# Is the golden armor (Garo) the only one that must be passed from ancestor to descendant?

Tags: garo

In *Garo: Honoo no Kokuin*, we see that the golden armor (Garo) can only be passed down to one's lineal descendants (for example, from Anna's father [the former Garo] to Leon and Alfonso).

What about the other armors, like Zoro and Gaia, though? Do they have any restrictions on who can use them? Regarding Zoro, in episode 24, we learn that

> Germán's child with Ximena is going to inherit Zoro. That doesn't necessarily mean that Zoro *has* to be passed lineally, but it does sort of suggest that that might be the case.

On the other hand, it looks like Gaia doesn't have any restrictions based on bloodline, since Raphael was able to pass Gaia onto Alfonso, and I don't see how Raphael could be a lineal ancestor of Alfonso - Raphael is not Alfonso's father (the king), nor his maternal grandfather (the former Garo), nor his paternal grandfather (presumably the previous king, who must be long dead), and anybody from Alfonso's great-grandparents' generation should also be dead.

Answers based on the tokusatsu version are welcome if they make sense in the context of the anime.

Answer (score 1):

According to my understanding, the Silver Knight's armor follows similar rules to the Golden Knight's. Note: I've heard it said a couple times that the third series Yami wo Terasu Mono was retroactively declared non-canon, which would get rid of the sole instance in which a Golden Armor was inherited by a random. Further note: YWTM was utterly disappointing making it the sole entry into the franchise I didn't watch completely.